# Implement multiple substitution sed commands on one line?

Tags: unix, sed, substitution

So the problem is as follows:

Using the sed command change the sets of permissions to the numeric equivalent, i.e. "rwx" is 7 "rw-" is 6, etc.

The problem is supposed to teach us to script and how to implement multiple sed commands one one line. I tried this but it keeps telling me no such file or directory. I can't seem to figure it out.

```
sed 's/rwx/7/' 's/rw-/6/' 's/r-x/5/' 's/r--/4/' 's/-wx/3/' 's/-w-/2/' 's/--x/1/' 's/---/0/' t1 >> t2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/rwx/7/;s/rw-/6/;s/r-x/5/;s/r--/4/;s/-wx/3/;s/-w-/2/;s/--x/1/;s/---/0/' t1 >> t2
```